# Computing the frequency into which x falls into the Borel $\delta$-algebra

Tags: clustering, nonparametric, stochastic-processes, metric, sigma-algebra

I'm currently trying to make sense of the papers:

1. Clustering processes by Daniil Ryabko ([link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1004.5194.pdf))
2. Online Clustering of Processes by Azadeh Khaleghi ([link](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v22/khaleghi12/khaleghi12.pdf))

Both of them make use of the following metric

[image]

Where $v(x,B)$ is defined in the following paragraph as follows

[image]

I'm finding it difficult to understand how I would go about computing such a $V(x,B)$ from the definition given as the text is very technical. Could anyone give me an example how I could compute such a quantity? Perhaps an easy example?

Answer (score 0):

By definition:

$$\nu(\mathbf{x},B)=\frac{\mathbf{1}_{n\geq m}}{n-m+1}\sum_{i=1}^{n-m+1}\mathbf{1}_{X_{i\cdots i+m-1\in B}}.$$

For a given $\mathbf{x}$,$n$,$m$, they are calculating the frequency of how many subsequences of the form $X_i,X_{i+1},\cdots,X_{i+m-1}$ fall into a fixed set $B$, where $i$ ranges from 1 to $n-m+1$. Hence why the denominator is $n-m+1$.

Comment: What is the set B? The definition states it's a partitioning of A into cubes? How would I compute if the subsequence falls into the set B?